How to configure the warning about reading an old doc version for each docs plugin instance?
When using versioning in Docusaurus and a user is viewing an old version of a doc, a message similar to what I've pasted below is displayed at the top of the doc.

This is documentation for [site name] #.#, which is no longer actively maintained. For up-to-date documentation, see the latest
version (#.#).

I'm using Docusaurus with multiple docs plugin instances. So for example we have an SDK for Web, React-Native, Android and iOS that each have their own docs plugin and versions.
But they all get that same message that has [site name] in it, which doesn't make sense. How can I customize this message so that it uses a unique name for each docs plugin instance?
